# How can we define $(F \times G) (f)$ in a general category, where $F, G$ functors, $f$ a map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $F,G$ be two functors in $A^I$, with $A$ an additive category.  Since the product $a \times b$ exists in $A$ for any objects $a, b$, define $(F \times G)(j) \equiv F(j) \times G(j), \ j \in I$.  Then I am almost done showing that $F\times G$ is a functor from $I$ to $A$.  I just need to define $(F\times G) (f)$ for map $f: i \to j$ in $\text{Hom}(I)$.  But how can that be done in general, without referring to $i,j$ as sets and taking elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a map $f:i\to j$, there are maps $$F(f):F(i)\to F(j), G(f):G(i)\to G(j).$$ Since $F(i)\times G(i)$ is the product of $F(i)$ and $G(i)$ and $F(j)\times G(j)$ is the product of $F(j)$ and $G(j)$, there exists a unique map $$(F\times G)(f):F(i)\times G(i) \to F(j)\times G(j)$$ such that the obvious diagrams commute. It is then a matter of technique to show that this defines a functor.

Comment: I don't get how you showed there is a unique such map knowing that each are a product and coproduct.

Comment: Oh, actually there's no need for the coproduct. I've edited my answer. The map $F(i)\times G(i)\to F(i) \to F(j)$ and the similar map $F(i)\times G(i) \to G(j)$ induce the map $(F\times G)(f):F(i)\times G(i) \to F(j)\times G(j)$.